# Kick all channels from confbridge together

Tags: asterisk

Is there any command in confbrdige by which I can kick all the channels from a conference? I can see command by which I can kick only one channel at a time but what if I want to kick all the channels from a conference room in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted the patch for

```
confbridge kick <conference> all
```

It is currently available in Asterisk V11 trunk

Comment: Are you sure all command is exist in asterisk ?
because i am trying to execute this command and saw like "No participant named 'all' found!" .

Comment: This code has been accepted into Asterisk trunk - it will not appear in V11 of Asterisk as it is a new feature.

Comment: Yes i search on asterisk forum and found like this feature is available on 12 version not 11

Answer (score 1):

you can kick all users with this command:

MeetMe kick [confno] all

Comment: Dear Mostafa I have asked for Confbridge not for meetme...I know about this command for meetme...kindly read the question carefully before replying...

Comment: please try this:  confbridge kick <conference> all

Comment: no, i haven't asterisk v.10, so i can't try this. yeah, i started asterisk about 3 month ago, i'm sorry. be success.

Answer (score -1):

```
CONTROLLER:

function kickallconference(){
     $conf= $this->uri->segment(3);
     $data = $this->confmodel->kickall_conf($conf);
     $i = 0;
    while($i < count($data)){
     $result['conf']= $conf;
     $result['channel']= $data[$i]['channel'];
     $this->load->view('hangup',$result);
     $i++;
    }

    }

MODEL:

function kickall_conf($cno){

    $sql = "SELECT channel from confnumber where confno='$cno' and status='ACTIVE'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result_array();
  }

VIEW:


            fputs($socket, "Action: ConfbridgeKick\r\n");
            fputs($socket, "Conference: $conf\r\n");
            fputs($socket, "Channel: $channel\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: please read the question carefully then answer to it...I never asked for a php script.